# How to apply vlookup() on sentences/complex text

Tags: excel, vlookup

I know how to apply `vlookup()` on a single/small value in excel. But I need to apply it on a complex(multi statement) text.
How can I do that?

Example:

**Table 1:**

Column A:

> thank you for your email and contacting us.
>
> by a copy of this email, we are forwarding your communication to our
>   ecommerce team on their mail id info@fakeemail.com, who will liase
>   with you on the said issue and revert to you shortly. 
>   may we request you to please bear with us till such time.
>
> sincerely,
>
> a name

**Table 2:**

```
+--------------------+----------+
|      Column A      | Column B |
+--------------------+----------+
| Same data as above |  true    |
+--------------------+----------+
```

`vlookup()` is written as-

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Table 2!A1:B1,2,0)
```

If `vlookup()` does not help with this sort of data, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is this data all in one cell, what words are you exactly trying to `vlookup()`?

Comment: yes, this entire data consists of one cell. There is a corresponding value attached to it in the adjcent column, say "true". I have another sheet where the same cell is present. I need to get the corresponding "true" or "false" value in the other sheet. So the vlookup() in not on any word but on the entire text. is this exercise possible in excel?

Comment: And have you tried the `vlookup()`? If both cells are the same and you indicate the correct column to return, then it will work. I'm not sure I see the issue here?

Comment: i have tried vlookup() but the result it gives is "#value". I guess the lookup data is too complex for excel to handle. Hence it is not able to perform function properly.

Comment: Then either your `vlookup()` is incorrectly written, which means you should post the code and the example data as it appears in the excel sheets, or it means the data isn't the same. For example one has more white space than the other

Comment: i tried trimming the data as well. Sill it gave the same #value! Also i pasted the same cell and applied the function, but still the same result.

Comment: So post some example code, otherwise we're going to have difficulty finding your issue. [We need a MCVE before we can assist further](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113284/discussion-between-eclairs-and-draken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vlookup()` won't work in this case as your text, that you are searching for, exceeds the 255 count limit. See the article [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/27/excel-vlookup-not-working/#vlookup-value-error)

Instead try what they mention in the article by using this formula:

```
=INDEX(C2:C7,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:B7= F$2,0),0))
```

Where:

- `F$2` is the value you want to match
- `C2:C7` is the column containing the value you want to return
- `B2:B7` is the column you are searching the value for

Hope that helps